# Trying to figure out how to compress css and js file using asset pipeline in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, compression, asset-pipeline, rack

I'm trying to understand what is going on with the asset pipeline.  I see that all my js and css files are being put into one global js and css file.  I also know it removes white space and comments, but does it really compress it to a gzip?

I also tried enabling Rack::Deflater, but I didn't see any file size changes on the network tab when doing inspection
    config.middleware.use Rack::Deflater

When running google tests, I see the following.  Im  trying to remove these errors
www.luminoto.com
Enable compression
Compressing resources with gzip or deflate can reduce the number of bytes sent over the network.
Enable compression for the following resources to reduce their transfer size by 356.2KiB (73% reduction).
Compressing https://www.luminoto.com/…tion-8e23d6ddb2dfed548ae7e2d067340ff4.js could save 242.9KiB (69% reduction).
Compressing https://www.luminoto.com/…ion-f325014fcdf855ccde6c2ea7d48b2df7.css could save 113.3KiB (87% reduction).
Hide details

Answer (score 0):

When assets are precompiled, Sprockets also generated the respective gzip files but you have to configure your web server in order to use compression and finally use that gzip files that were previously generated (otherwise the web server will try to compress it again)

You can see more details on this Rails guide: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#gzip-compression

Comment: thanks.  i ended up doing that and using rack - zippy.  Only thing it my font awesome fonts arent showing up in IE11